# Configuration of XBEE S1 Modules

Tags: uart, xbee

I have two Xbee Series 1 Modules. I want to configure one as transmitter and one as receiver. Could someone please recommend a good website or a tutorial link to do the same ? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digi International has an [entire website dedicated to examples](http://examples.digi.com/), including some for just getting started.  It includes a [Basic XBee 802.15.4 (Series 1) Chat](http://examples.digi.com/get-started/basic-xbee-802-15-4-chat/) that sounds like what you're looking for.